# Generate a random integer in Idris

Tags: idris

How can one generate a random integer in Idris 1.3.3?

Example program that doesn't work:

```
module Random

import Effect.Random --This gets me access to the rndInt function
```

I run the program as follows:

```
idris random.idr -p effects
```

Trying the `rndInt` function in the REPL, I get the following error message:

```
*random> rndInt 1 10
(input):Can't infer argument m to rndInt
```

Please include the full source code in your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on Alissa Tung's answer, here's the full working source code, including setting the random seed (srand) with the system time:

```
module Random

import Effect.Random 
import Effects
import System

main : IO ()
main = do
    t <- time
    n <- run $ do 
        srand t
        rndInt 1 100
    putStrLn $ show n
```

Run with:

```
idris random.idr -p effects
```

Output:

```
*random> :exec main
88
*random> :exec main
96
*random> :exec main
19
```